# Has anyone asked on meta.stackexchange.com about ways to automate hard-science tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

When someone puts [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science) tag on a question, currently a moderator has to manually add the message explaining the requirements for answers.

**Has anyone ever asked on meta.stackexchange.com about whether they could add a feature to automatically annotate a question that carries a given tag?** If that could be automated, it would take work off of moderators, confusion off of newbies, and would address issues like [this one](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4094/is-there-a-way-to-remove-this-bug-related-to-the-hard-science-tag). It could also maybe open the door to more exotic tags, like the [hope-based](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hope-based) tag that @MolbOrg and I were discussing [here](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/4270/putting-opinion-based-questions-on-hold-too-fast/4271?noredirect=1#comment11483_4271) only somewhat tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: seems to be the story http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/3818/20315 and other post there as well